# Disappearing Application variables

Tags: coldfusion, application.cfc

I have a problem where I set APPLICATION variables and they seem to disappear within 3-30 minutes. I have set the CF Administrator to 7 days default timeout and also set this as the timeout in the Application.cfc. Any ideas why these variables could be just disappearing?

Comment: Are you doing anything that calls the `onApplicationStart()` in Application.cfc?

Comment: No I'm not, not setting a timeout seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would disable the timeout altogether. Also, since application variables are scoped globally, it's likely concurrent operations are changing the variables.

Also, check the name of the application. If two deployment share the same name, they will compete for the same application variables.

Comment: I've checked the application names, I'm not sure how to disable timeout altogether?

Comment: I meant remove applicationTimeout from application.cfc. I was, also considering other possibilities that are a bit uncommon: Restarting of web server will cause these variables to die. Also, if you are in a clustered environment, you may be hitting different servers, hence loosing the variables.

Comment: OK I'll try that, it's not any of those other things as I'm just working locally on development machine.